# How can I access react context in react-styleguidist's Wrapper component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, react-styleguidist

#### What I want:

I'm trying to add a dynamic theme option to a [react-styleguidist](https://react-styleguidist.js.org/) project I'm working on. Following the idea laid out in [this unfinished and closed pr](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/pull/1434), I added a custom `ThemeSwitcher` component, which is a select menu that is rendered in the table of contents sidebar. Selecting an option should update the `brand` context, which renders the corresponding theme using styled-components' `BrandProvider`. It should function like the demo included with the closed pr: https://fancy-sg.surge.sh/.

#### What's not working:

I can't access the same context in my `ThemedWrapper` as is provided and updated in the `StyleguideWrapper` and `ThemeSwitcher`. Examining the tree in the React Components console, it looks like react-styleguidist may render `ReactExample` *outside* of the `StyleguideRenderer`, which means it loses the context from the provider in that component.

Assuming I'm correct about the context not updating in `ThemedWrapper` due to it being located outside of `StyleGuideRenderer`, two high level ideas I have (but haven't been able to figure out how to do) are:

1. Find the correct component that is an ancestor of both `StyleGuideRenderer` *and* `ReactExample` in the react-styleguidist library and add the `BrandProvider` there so that `ThemedWrapper` now has context access
2. Some other context configuration that I haven't found yet that will allow two components to consume the same context without having a provider as an ancestor (is this possible??)

#### What I have:

Here are the condensed versions of the relevant code I'm using.

**brand-context.js** (exports context and provider, inspired by [Kent C Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively)

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

const BrandStateContext = createContext();
const BrandSetContext = createContext();

function BrandProvider({ children, theme }) {
  const [brand, setBrand] = useState(theme);
  return (
    <BrandStateContext.Provider value={brand}>
      <BrandSetContext.Provider value={(val) => setBrand(val)}>
        {children}
      </BrandSetContext.Provider>
    </BrandStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useBrandState() {
  return useContext(BrandStateContext);
}

function useBrandSet() {
  return useContext(BrandSetContext);
}

export { BrandProvider, useBrandState, useBrandSet };
```

**StyleGuideWrapper.jsx** (Copy of rsg-components/StyleguideRenderer, with addition of ThemeSwitcher component to toggle theme from ui; passed in styleguide config as `StyleGuideRenderer`)

```
import React from 'react';
import cx from 'clsx';
import Styled from 'rsg-components/Styled';

import ThemeSwitcher from './ThemeSwitcher';
import { BrandProvider } from './brand-context';

export function StyleGuideRenderer({ children, classes, hasSidebar, toc }) {
  return (
    <BrandProvider>
      <div className={cx(classes.root, hasSidebar && classes.hasSidebar)}>
        <main className={classes.content}>
          {children}
        </main>
        {hasSidebar && (
          <div className={classes.sidebar} data-testid="sidebar">
            <section className={classes.sidebarSection}>
              <ThemeSwitcher classes={classes} />
            </section>
            {toc}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </BrandProvider>
  );
}

StyleGuideRenderer.propTypes = propTypes;

export default Styled(styles)(StyleGuideRenderer);
```

**ThemeSwitcher.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Styled from 'rsg-components/Styled';

import { useBrandSet, useBrandState } from './brand-context';

const ThemeSwitcher = ({ classes }) => {
  const brand = useBrandState();
  const setBrand = useBrandSet();
  const onBrandChange = (e) => setBrand(e.target.value);

  const brands = ['foo', 'bar'];

  return (
    <label className={classes.root}>
      Brand
      <select value={brand} onChange={onBrandChange}>
        {brands.map((brand) => (
          <option key={brand} value={brand}>{brand}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </label>
  );
};

export default Styled(styles)(ThemeSwitcher);
```

**ThemedWrapper.jsx** (passed in styleguide config as `Wrapper`, and wraps each example component to provide them to styled-components)

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { BrandStateContext } from './brand-context';

const LibraryProvider = ({ brand, children }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={brand}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
  );
};

function ThemedWrapper({ children }) {
  return (
    <BrandStateContext.Consumer>
      {brand => (
        <LibraryProvider brand={brand}>{children}</LibraryProvider>
      )}
    </BrandStateContext.Consumer>
  );
}

export default ThemedWrapper;
```

Comment: I found a solution that works but requires overwriting more of the source code, so I opened an issue in the library proposing a fix: https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/issues/1639. Will update with an answer here when I determine the best resolution.